# where are linux installation files located?

Tags: linux, kernel

Where are the Linux os installation files located? why are the installation files not run every time an OS is booted and only during the first boot ? How does it know that the OS is already installed ?

Comment: This seems like a school test question.

Comment: i am trying to learn linux booting process in detail,and came across with this doubt in mind.i am a beginner and sry if it is kind of too basic qn . would be helpful if you could give me some insight about it.and i am not a school student and this is not my test qn either. i just wondered how it happens and was curious to know about the process that's it.

Comment: I understand. The comment was explaining my downvote because it really looks like a test question. IMO, better way to ask things on SE is to show that you read something / tried to understand something (and what it was) and then ask more specifically. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation files for a Linux distribution are stored on the installation medium (a USB stick, or an optical disk of some sort, typically, and there are other possible sources). When you boot the installation medium, it knows that it’s supposed to install the operating system because that’s what it’s designed to do; in some cases, it serves multiple purposes and it will ask what to do — install, or start a live environment, or a recovery environment.

The installed system is separate, and doesn’t include the installation files. It thus “knows” that it’s not supposed to install itself.

On a computer on which a Linux distributions has been installed, nothing prevents you from booting an installation system, and then the installation will start over.

Comment: so if i download a ubuntu iso ,then the iso will have installation files in it but while installing the os to hard disk the installation files are skipped and only the kernel and initrd are installed.is my understanding right ?

Comment: Nearly; there’s much more to install than the kernel and initramfs, but yes, the installation files aren’t copied.

Answer (score 0):

> Where are the Linux os installation files located?

Anywhere your PC is able to boot from: USB flash stick, an HDD/SSD, PCI-E expansion card (nvme drive), a CD-DVD ROM, network (PXE).

> why are the installation files not run every time an OS is booted and only during the first boot ?

Simple. When no OS is installed UEFI/BIOS will try to boot from all available devices and eventually find Linux installation files of any of the mentioned media.

For normal BIOS systems HDD/SSD is the preferred boot media, so after the installation it will be chosen first and installation media will be skipped.

For UEFI systems Linux once installed adds itself as the first boot option and again the installation media will not be booted by default any longer.

> How does it know that the OS is already installed ?

There's no distinction for BIOS/UEFI if something is installed or not. It just boots what's available. When Linux gets installed it becomes available and gets loaded first.

Comment: _There's no distinction for BIOS/UEFI if something is installed or not. It just boots what's available. When Linux gets installed it becomes available and gets loaded first._ .so if i already have ubuntu installed in a partition and again try to install ubuntu from usb in the same partition,won't there be any warnings stating an os is already installed in that partition or something ?

Comment: That’s up to the installer. Most should warn before overwriting, but that’s a feature of the installation tool, not of the firmware (BIOS or UEFI).

Comment: got a clear idea that i was looking for .thanks a ton ! @StephenKitt,@Artem S. Tashkinov